# Attempting to use CSS top property on a SWF file, but it's not working

Tags: css, flash, flex4, swfobject

I'm trying to position my Flex app so that it's further down the page, but I can't get it working. It's still appearing in the top left. Here is the HTML, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <title>Page</title>
   <style type="text/css">
       body { margin: 0px; overflow: hidden; }
       #swf {top:50%;}
   </style>

   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

   swfobject.embedSWF( "link_to_the_swf", "swf", "100%", "100%", "10.0.0", "playerProductInstall.swf", flashVars, params );
   </script>
</head>
<body scroll="no">

   <div id="swf">
      <p>Alternative content</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: After reading [this message](http://groups.google.com/group/swfobject/msg/c1f0fc0f72f17f49), I tried wrapping the swf div in another one and setting the top property on the parent div, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `top` alone. You need to give the `div` either `position: relative` or use `margin-top` / `padding-top`.

Comment: Thanks so much, works great. The other answers were handy as well!

Answer (score 0):

top requires a positioning other than static, which is the default. Try:

```
#swf {position:relative; top:50%;}
```

However, if you want to put it in the middle of a large container and have it centered instead of starting at the middle and going down you could do:

```
#swf {margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving body `position: relative`. Then add `position: absolute` (or `relative` I suppose) to #swf

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the body a height as well. Something like body { height: 100%; }